# Flexbox Holy Grail Layout: Fixed Header, Fixed Left Nav, Fluid Content Area, Fixed Right Sidebar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm attempting to build the "Holy Grail" layout using Flexbox.

- Fixed Header
- Fixed, Collapsible, Scrollable Left Nav
- Flexible Content Area
- Fixed, Collapsible, Scrollable Right Nav

**See below:**

[image]

I have everything working, except for the height of the "app" area underneath the header. Right now it's **100vh** (100% of the viewport height), but this includes the 64px header.

I attempted calc(100vh - 64px), but that doesn't jive well with flex.

**Here's my basic HTML structure:**

```
<main>
    <header></header>
    <app>
        <nav>Left Nav</nav>
        <article>Content</article>
        <aside>Right Nav</aside>
    </app>
</main>
```

**And the supporting CSS:**

```
main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

header { 
    z-index: 0;
    flex: 0 0 64px;
    display: flex;
}

app {
    flex: 1 1 100vh;
    display: flex;
}

nav {
    flex: 0 0 256px;
    order: 0;
}

article {
    flex: 1 1 100px;
    order: 1;
}

aside {
    flex: 0 0 256px;
    order: 2;
}
```

**[- - - Full jsFiddle Here - - -](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMoore/LLfcL28u/19/)**

**[- - - Simplified jsFiddle Here - - -](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMoore/mu748why/)**

Comment: FYI, the `flex` tag is used for Apache Flex.  The `flexbox` tag refers to CSS flex layouts.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There were some CSS conflicts with `<main>` and `<body>`, and all I had to do was remove the `<main>` wrapper, then add the flex definitions directly to the page body.

**[- - - Here's the full working jdFiddle - -](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMoore/LLfcL28u/24/) -**

**[- - - Here's the simplified jdFiddle - - -](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMoore/mu748why/4/)**

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  z-index: 0;
  flex: 0 64px;
  display: flex;
}

app {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  flex: 0 0 256px;
  order: 0;
}

article {
  flex: 1;
  order: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

aside {
  flex: 0 0 256px;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<app>
  <nav>Left Nav</nav>
  <article></article>
  <aside>Right Nav</aside>
</app>
```

Comment: This answer, while it works well in current Chrome (47) and Safari (9), doesn't seem to work properly in Firefox (44).

This seems to be a recurring issue I see with layouts like this coded in flexbox on FF - it doesn't seem to respect the ability of a single panel (the nav and/or article panels in your example) to have a flex-calculated height and overflow-y setting. Instead, the entire page scrolls.

I can't seem to get it to work properly in FF - maybe some prefixes are missing?

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  Is using the HTML tag `<app>` semantically correct? Or should one really use `div id="app">` instead?  Or are you using a framework such as AngularJs?

Comment: @J.KyMarsh Just add `overflow: auto;` to `app` selector and fixed header will work in FF too.

Comment: `<app>` has been removed from HTML5, because it was a precursor to `<applet>`. It has no business in a modern web page.